# Is my pineapple bromeliad plant dead

Tags: diagnosis, office-gardening, bromeliads

About 10 days ago my plant was healthy and vibrant, but now the pineapple has gone brown and I can't work out why. This is my first attempt at gardening with a few plants in my office it brighten it up a bit.

I tried drying the soil out.
I tried watering the plant well with plant food.
I tried moving it to the front window so it gets lots of sunlight.

Is my plant beyond saving?

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to express my admiration for getting this far. I have tried many times to grow a pineapple, and they all just rotted.

Answer (score 1):

Just cut off the stem with the pineapple on top, at the base where it arises from the leaves, carefully, so as not to damage any other growth, or just above the leaves a bit lower down on that stem. Although the main mother plant will die within a few weeks, if you take care of it properly, it should produce new growth around the edges, although as it is in a  pot, maybe not  so much as it would in the ground. All fruits from plants are technically seed cases of one type or another, and each will, if not picked and eaten, shrivel and die back, which is what's happened to your pineapple fruit. Info and care instructions here: [What to Do to a Pineapple Plant After Picking the Pineapple](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/pineapple-plant-after-picking-pineapple-54608.html#:%7E:text=After%20you%20have%20harvested%20the,removed%20from%20the%20main%20plant).

UPDATE
On closer inspection (following your comment) I can see a darker, slightly shrivelled area on the stem holding the fruit, about halfway up, with white spots which look like maybe mildew or mould. I also see tiny white specks on top of the lower leaves, they might just be dust or something, I can't tell, so inspect the whole plant thoroughly. Either way, remove the stem with the fruit at the base, where it joins the rest of the plant, since it clearly has a problem anyway.

Comment: I have several of the same plant bought together and only this one has developed issues, are you sure its just is time ? If so id have expected the others to be doing the same.